# jQuery double clicking on link with slideToggle that has a Stop function sets a static height

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

[image]

This one is very weird.

I have a standard `slideToggle` on a link to show and hide a Container div. On this link I have put `stop()` to prevent click build up so the Container div doesn't go up and down continuously when you click on the link multiple times.

**The weird problem I have**

When I click on the `slideToggle` link twice, or in other words if I double click the link, it sets a static hight and breaks.

See working fiddle below

**How to reproduce the issue**

1. Run the fiddle, click on the link "TWO" and then "THREE". Everything works fine.
2. Then click on "TWO" again and double click "SHOW HIDE ALL" toggle link and click "THREE". All of a sudden, the wrapper div has a fixed height to it. If I click "SHOW HIDE ALL" link just once everything works fine.

Can you please tell me why this happens?

FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/cwe8emgu/2/

Answer (score 0):

Pass `clearQueue` parameter as `true` in `.stop()` function.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/cwe8emgu/5/

JS:

```
 $('.backToDashboard a').click(function() {
      $('.wrapper').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow', function() {});
    });
```

**Or**

Remove .stop() function from the `$('.backToDashboard a')` click handler.

```
 $('.backToDashboard a').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slideToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/cwe8emgu/4/

**Explanation:** https://api.jquery.com/stop/

> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now still be displayed, **but will be a fraction of its previous height**. Callback functions are not called.

Comment: But the problem is, if I keep clicking the SHOW HIDE ALL link few times, the wrapper keeps closing and opening continuously.

Comment: Thanks KK. But Adding `true` to clearQueue breaks the smooth slideup and effect when I double click the link. :(